# use JSTL variable on JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

How can i use JSTL variable as following:

```
         <c:set var="datetime" value="${fn:split(starttime,' ')}" />
         <c:set var="date" value="${fn:replace(datetime[0],':',',')}" />
```

to be used later on something like:

```
         <c:if test="${param.cid!=null}">
         <%
              Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
              d.set(out.print(<c:out value="${date}"/>);
         %>
         </c:if>
```

**Edited**:

I finally did some experiments and found something like this:

```
         <% Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            if(pageContext.getAttribute("date") != null)
            { 
               String datez = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("date"); 
               String dates[] = datez.split(","); 
               String date0 = dates[0]; 
               String date1 = dates[1]; 
               String date2 = dates[2]; 
               int int0 = Integer.parseInt(date0); 
               int int1 = Integer.parseInt(date1) - 1; 
               int int2 = Integer.parseInt(date2); 
               c.set(int0,int1,int2); 
             } 
          %>
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: Pre- and postprocessing logic belongs in normal Java code which is exeucted/controlled by a Servlet class.

Comment: Could you please give me exact solution? code snippet perhaps? thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what "starttime" looks like  and tell us what you want to accomplish. Maybe we can suggest a solution.

Comment: hi @rickz, I just did some experiments and found something like this:  <%  if(pageContext.getAttribute("date") != null){
                String datez = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("date");
                String dates[] = datez.split(",");
                String date0 = dates[0];
                String date1 = dates[1];
                String date2 = dates[2];

                int int0 = Integer.parseInt(date0);
                int int1 = Integer.parseInt(date1) - 1;
                int int2 = Integer.parseInt(date2);
                c.set(int0,int1,int2);
        }
%>

Answer (score 0):

You can't use expression language inside scriptlets, because they should contain only Java code. By the way usually scriptlets are poor practice and the [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqz.html) and [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) are meant to replace them.